# How do I make an application immune to 'show desktop'?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Is there any way I can specify for a particular application to never be hidden when I press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or click show desktop in Windows 7?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this or an application that provides the functionality you need. The direction i would take is writing a small [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/) script with a infinite loop making the window constantly active.

Example 1

```
    While 1
      For $i = 1 To 100
    WinActivate("[CLASS:Notepad]", "")
Next
Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

*This example will keep the window class "Notepad" continually active even if the show desktop button is clicked *WinActivate* focuses on the window specified. I have added a sleep of 100MS so as not to use 100% CPU usage.

Depending on the language used to create the application that would not hide on "show desktop" one could hook the *form_resize* event (In VB6 Language) and if triggered show the application window as this is triggered on win+d or "Show Desktop".

I would just create a small script in Autoit (the easiest solution).

Good Luck

EDIT: As "Bavi_H" suggested, one could also continually set the "Window" state as "Restored" by replacing the following

```
WinActivate("[CLASS:Notepad]", "")
```

TO

```
WinSetState("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", @SW_RESTORE)
```

Comment: `WinActivate` keeps Notepad active, but prevents you from using any other window. To just keep Notepad open, try using this instead: `WinSetState("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", @SW_RESTORE)`